# I'm getting an 404 error because the requested source is not available

Tags: java, jsp

I'm getting a 404 error on my login page.

I'm still very newbie at this and this is probably a silly question.

Maybe my mistake is on the path, but I can't seem to find it alone. That's why I need some guidance, please. The .jsp reference is `login.jsp` which should call `Login.java` which would have a dispatcher to `config.jsp` - which is inside WEB-INF.

This is the error:

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gGB30.png)

This is my project:

[project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWc4X.png)

My `login.jsp`

```
<form method="post" action="/Login">
     <input type="text" id="username"  name="username" placeholder="Usuário">
     <input type="password" id="password"  name="password" placeholder="Senha">
     <input type="submit"  value="Entrar">
</form>
```

My `web.xml`:

```
<servlet>
      <servlet-name>Login</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>Login</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>Login</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/Login</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

My `Login.java`:

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/Login"})
public class Login extends HttpServlet {
    
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext()
                .getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/config.jsp");
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        
        String username = request.getParameter("username");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
        if(username.equals("admin") && password.equals("admin")){
            session.setAttribute("username", username);
            
            doGet(request, response);
        }
        else {
            response.sendRedirect("login.jsp");
        }
        
        
    };
}
```

I don't know if you need any more info, but if necessary I can add it.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Ideally you shouldnt use images of your errors.  It looks to me you have set you `urlPatterns` to `"/Login"` so your login page is likely at `<your host/domain>/Login`

Comment: I'm sorry about that, I didn't know. But Jesus, you're right. Now I get an exception report.
Error instantiating servlet class [Login].

Comment: You should either use web.xml or the annotations to configure your servlets, not both. It might be conflicting somewhere.